# linux startup usb 2-8 : dvb_usb_v2 : did not find the firmware file

Tags: boot, usb, firmware

After upgrading Linux Mint to version 19 Tara, my Ubuntu Mate version, located on another disk, starts up with an error

```
usb 2-8 : dvb_usb_v2 : did not find the firmware file ...
```

The same error occurs when Mint 19 starts up.

I can't find any answer and it looks like everything starts up fine in Ubuntu and Mint.
Can anyone tell me what might be the problem?

Many thanks,
Marc

Comment: Please add more debug information. Which device is connected on usb 2-8? Please add output of `lsusb` with connected device.